# Couldn't segue to another view controller from textField

Tags: ios, swift

I want to have the pretty simple transition from the home view where the user enters the text in the textfield, then have its segue go to the next view controller. I did implement the function **textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool** which tries to perform the segue, but didn't get the desired result. 
Here's the part of the code

```
class LogInVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var logInLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var logInField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        NSLog("LogIn view loaded, setting delegate")

        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        NSLog("viewWillAppear: Performing possible queued updates")
        textFieldShouldReturn(textField: logInField)            
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard let autoCheckInVC = segue.destination as?
            AutocheckInVC else {
            preconditionFailure("Wrong destination type: \(segue.destination)")
        }

        guard logInField.text != nil else {
            preconditionFailure("Text property should not be nil")
        }

    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "AutoCheckInVC", sender: self)
        return true
    }   
}
```

Any quick help for debugging this would be so greatly appreciated. I have tried quite much time fixing this, but I haven't found the way out!!!

Comment: What´s not working, the segue or passing the data from your textField to the next textField?

Comment: the segue is not operating like I wanted to be! I'm not trying to save the passing data from the textField or something equivalently

Comment: Also, I don't know why there why the line **        textFieldShouldReturn(textField: logInField)            
** complains about "result of call to this method is unused".

Comment: is `prepare(for segue: sender: )` getting called? You would also better call `super.viewDidAppear()`. Also, you have to make `LoginVC` conform to `UITextFieldDelegate` and in `viewDidLoad` set `logInField.delegate = self`. Otherwise the function won't be called on your textField return action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few errors in your code:

1. To be able to call `textFieldShouldReturn` you need to inherit from `UITextFieldDelegate` and set the delegate of your `textField`, `logInField.delegate = self`
2. Don´t call `textFieldShouldReturn` from `viewDidAppear`
3. Use the latest syntax for the method `textFieldShouldReturn`
4. You got the warning *result of call to this method is unused* because it was never called since you never had the `delegates`

Try this code instead of yours:

```
class LogInVC: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var logInLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var logInField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        NSLog("LogIn view loaded, setting delegate")

        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        logInField.delegate = self
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        NSLog("viewWillAppear: Performing possible queued updates")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard let autoCheckInVC = segue.destination as?
            ViewController else {
                preconditionFailure("Wrong destination type: \(segue.destination)")
        }

        guard logInField.text != nil else {
            preconditionFailure("Text property should not be nil")
        }

    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "AutoCheckInVC", sender: self)
        return true
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation and for pointing out the importance of requiring to import the delegate. Also, I don't think I need the function `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)  `, since the segue is already performed inside the function `textFieldShouldReturn`.

Comment: @Goldie np glad to help you. Good luck with your project.

Comment: actually, I'm doing the whole test again for this one, then encountering this problem: this segue actually transition `LogInVC` to 'AutoCheckInVC` twice than it's supposed to be do it once for all. I inspect that there's something wrong inside this func `textFieldShouldReturn()`, especially when calling `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "AutoCheckInVC", sender: self)`. Any suggestion for the fix since it's crucial?